# Validating token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, token

The query regards the method for validating an access token to the application's API.

From the rails [api link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/), when searching for `token`, the documentation has evolved for the private method to `authenticate`

While

```
Apikey.exists?(access_token: token)
```

is obvious, the newer version is rather opaque to me

```
ActiveSupport::SecurityUtils.secure_compare(
  ::Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(token),
  ::Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(TOKEN)
)
```

What is the allCAPS version of the token representing?  A stored **and encrypted** value of the token for that connecting entity, say User?  This implies that the query URL needs to have a parameter to identify the `User`.  Is that wise to pass it via a parameter, even if done under SSL ?

Comment: Where did find the second snippet?

Comment: using the link for the api and searching for `token`   resulting in page for ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token

Comment: That's a http token example. In it, there is only one token (that constant). Perhaps, this is not what you need.

Comment: "What is the allCAPS version of the token representing" - the constant, defined above in the code.

Comment: "This implies that the query URL needs to have a parameter to identify the User" - I don't see from where you draw this. In this concrete example, token is passed via request header. but in any scenario, you have to pass it _somehow_. Else how can you authenticate the user?

Comment: Below on the page, you have per-user token examles.

Comment: Yes, I saw the per-user token example.  however the constant defined this way `TOKEN = "secret"` would never be applied in practice (unless I am interpreting wildly wrong!).  I assumed it meant to call an encrypted key associated with the user (as it should be secret) to compare it with the one submitted in the header.

Comment: Sometimes you don't need per-user tokens (you might not have any users even), and one global token is good enough.